# Do recursive stories exist in English?

Tags: idioms

In Russian, for example, there is such thing as `докучные сказки`. Like:

```
У попа была собака, он ее любил.
Она съела кусок мяса, он ее убил.
В землю закопал, надпись написал:
  Repeat this story again and again.
```

It's like: A priest had a dog, the priest loved it. The dog ate a piece of meat, the priest killed it, buried and wrote: the same phrase from beginning.
Does such things exist in English?

Comment: [dogs eat meat or a piece of meat]

Comment: Voting to close the Duplicate Question : It already Exists & It has answers here [[ https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/319475/do-recursive-stories-exist-in-english ]] ; This is a Duplicate Question ! Voting to close the Duplicate Question

Answer (score 2):

We have songs that end where they started: a cycle song The most famous is probably:

**There's a Hole in the Bucket**
"A circle song is one that comes back to where it started and begins again. It can go on indefinitely".
[Explanation of cycle song](https://A%20circle%20song%20is%20one%20that%20comes%20back%20to%20where%20it%20started%20and%20begins%20again.%20It%20can%20go%20on%20indefinitely.%20This%20is%20the%20amusing%20story%20of%20Henry%20and%20Maria.%20Their%20bucket%20leaks%20and%20she%20wants%20him%20to%20fix%20it,%20but%20that%20never%20happens.)

One of the most famous renditions of the song was by Harry Belafonte and Odetta,  originally performed in 1959!

You can hear it here: Song
It is really charming. :)

[words to the song](https://genius.com/Harry-belafonte-a-hole-in-the-bucket-lyrics)

Comment: The Song that Never Ends is another famous one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Song_That_Never_Ends

Answer (score 2):

I'm aware of a short cyclic story (no idea of the original source):

> It was a dark and stormy night and the sailors said to the Captain, "Captain, tell us a story" and so he began, "It was a dark and stormy night and the sailors said to the Captain, "Captain, tell us a story" and so he began ..."

Answer (score 0):

There's a joke 'meme'…

> You go to work to earn the money to buy the food to get the strength to go to work to ...